# write or append text to a existing file

Tags: vb.net

I have a start a new software that save all my text inserted on my textbox in to a text file every thing work fine but wen it save to the file the file have on reference , how can i save my content with file extention .txt
I have try with this method but the file have no extension, i miss something on my code.
After to search every were i found the solution for it but how can i append new lines to an existing file with out delete any content all ready there

This is my code

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnMapaEndereco_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMapaEndereco.Click

    If VerificaNavegador() Then

        Try
            Dim rua As String = String.Empty
            Dim cidade As String = String.Empty
            Dim estado As String = String.Empty
            Dim cep As String = String.Empty
            Dim path As String = "c:\Mymaps"
            Dim FileName As String = "C:\Mymaps\mymaps.txt"

            Dim path2 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop


            Dim consultaEndereco As New StringBuilder()
            consultaEndereco.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

            Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\MyMapsDataSearchQueris.txt"
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            objWriter.WriteLine("rua: " + txtRua.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine("cidade: " + txtCidade.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine("estado: " + txtEstado.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine("cep: " + txtCep.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine("-----------fim de pesquisa-----------")
            objWriter.Close()


            ' monta a rua como parte da consulta
            If txtRua.Text <> String.Empty Then
                rua = txtRua.Text.Replace(" ", "+")
                consultaEndereco.Append(rua + "," & "+")
            End If

            ' monta a cidade como parte da consulta
            If txtCidade.Text <> String.Empty Then
                cidade = txtCidade.Text.Replace(" ", "+")
                consultaEndereco.Append(cidade + "," & "+")
            End If

            ' monta o estado como parte da consulta
            If txtEstado.Text <> String.Empty Then
                estado = txtEstado.Text.Replace(" ", "+")
                consultaEndereco.Append(estado + "," & "+")
            End If

            ' monta o cep como parte da consulta
            If txtCep.Text <> String.Empty Then
                cep = txtCep.Text.ToString()
                consultaEndereco.Append(cep)
            End If

            ' passa a url com a query string para o controle webbrowser
            webb1x.Navigate(consultaEndereco.ToString())


        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Não foi possível obter o Mapa")

        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("O Naveador usado é Incompatível", "Aviso")
    End If


End Sub

Private Function VerificaNavegador() As Boolean
    Dim versaoNavegador As Integer, RegVal As Integer
    Try
        ' obtem a versão instalada do IE
        Using Wb As New WebBrowser()
            versaoNavegador = Wb.Version.Major
        End Using

        ' define a versão do IE
        If versaoNavegador >= 11 Then
            RegVal = 11001
        ElseIf versaoNavegador = 10 Then
            RegVal = 10001
        ElseIf versaoNavegador = 9 Then
            RegVal = 9999
        ElseIf versaoNavegador = 8 Then
            RegVal = 8888
        Else
            RegVal = 7000
        End If

        ' define a chave atual
        Dim Key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", True)
        Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        Key.Close()
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function


Private Sub btnMapaCoordenadas_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMapaCoordenadas.Click


    If VerificaNavegador() Then
        If txtLatitude.Text = String.Empty Or txtLongitude.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Forneça os valores para a latitude e a longitude.", "Dados inválidos")
        End If

        Try
            Dim lat As String = String.Empty
            Dim lon As String = String.Empty

            Dim consultaEndereco As New StringBuilder()
            consultaEndereco.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

            ' monta a latitude como parte da consulta
            If txtLatitude.Text <> String.Empty Then
                lat = txtLatitude.Text
                consultaEndereco.Append(lat + "%2C")
            End If

            ' monta a longitude como parte da consulta
            If txtLongitude.Text <> String.Empty Then
                lon = txtLongitude.Text
                consultaEndereco.Append(lon)
            End If

            webb1x.Navigate(consultaEndereco.ToString())

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error")

        End Try

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("O Naveador usado é Incompatível", "Aviso")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles splitContainer1.Panel1.Paint

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
    Form3.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the line like below :

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
```